# Applescript for Outlook - mark messages as read

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I am looking for an Applescript to mark messages as read within Outlook 2011 for Mac.

I have not been able to identify the correct property to set.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set myMessages to selection
    repeat with aMessage in myMessages
        set aMessage's is read to true
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: in Outlook 16.5, i had to change the line `set aMessage's is read to true` to `tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to set aMessage's is read to true`. I'm not sure why the second `tell application...` is necessary, but without it, I consistently received a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is great, if you want to select the message(s) to mark as read.  but with Outlook on Mac putting Calendar invites in Deleted as "unread"...this version will run for you and can be set up to do it's thing from cron as often as you would like.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    repeat with afolder in deleted items
        set aMsg to (every message of afolder where its is read is not true)
        repeat with aMessage in aMsg
            set aMessage's is read to true
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```